# How to split polygons by overlapping feature?

Tags: r

How can I divide the multiple overlapping polygons into multiple non-overlapping polygons? Here is an example: I would like to divide the long yellow polygon in the image into 3 polygons based on where it touches the other two.

```
library(spData)
library(sf)

seine_buff_5km = st_buffer(seine, dist = 5000)

tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(seine_buff_5km) +
  tm_fill( col = "name", alpha =.5) +
tm_shape(seine) +
  tm_lines()
```

[image: Seine]

Of course, I would like to do that for a larger data set with many more polygons. I guess one way to do it is subtract all polygons in an sf object from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`st_intersection` on a single object will chop it into non-overlapping parts:

```
> bi = st_intersection(seine_buff_5km)
> bi
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 513345.8 ymin: 6655432 xmax: 884953.8 ymax: 6943863
epsg (SRID):    2154
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
   name                       geometry n.overlaps origins
1 Marne POLYGON ((658951.7 6862882,...          1       1
2 Marne POLYGON ((657550.3 6852588,...          2    1, 2
3 Seine POLYGON ((517155.1 6930721,...          1       2
4 Seine POLYGON ((695195.4 6815345,...          2    2, 3
5 Yonne MULTIPOLYGON (((711168.3 68...          1       3
```

The `origins` column is a "list-column" that shows which of the original parts form the new part. When plotted in unique colours the five parts look like this:

[image]

Note how the green part is treated as a single object because it isn't quite cut into parts by the other polygons.

The fifth row (blue polygon, Yonne), is shown as a MULTIPOLYGON because there is a tiny sliver cut off above the orange polygon.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perhaps there is a way to divide the lines by where they touch and then buffer them?

Comment: That sounds like you really have a different question... what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Well I would like to divide the above polygons into six polygons based on where the lines or the polygons touch. I am not primarily interested in the yellow and the orange intersection. Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: I don't see how you get six polygons. Do you really want to get five line segments from the three line features in the original `seine` object?

Comment: Yes, exactly divided by where they touch. The original dataset contains of buffers around country borders. I thought that with a solution to this simple example, I could then solve the task for country borders so that I have a buffer for each unique two contiguous states.

Comment: I think you need to start again with a question that states your actual problem - this seemingly isn't going in the right direction...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317267/find-borders-between-all-unique-country-pairs-with-r